# Why does the data.table give an error for large datasets (integer vs double)

Tags: r, integer, double, data.table

I am an R beginner and I am currently doing a trend analysis (rkt) of a large datasets of water temperatures and I am using data.table to carry out this analysis. My data set looks like this:

```
      RiverStationID Year Month WaterTemp
   1:            362 1992     1      1.80
   2:            362 1992     2      5.90
   3:            362 1992     3      6.40
   4:            362 1992     4      6.30
   5:            362 1992     5      9.40

42654:           1519 2005    11     21.36
```

The code I am using has been working fine for most of the data sets except for some sets which are larger than the rest. The code keeps giving me this error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(WT.mean, , j = as.list(c(unlist(rkt(Year,  : 
  Column 1 of result for group 49 is type 'integer' but expecting type 'double'. Column types must be consistent for each group.
```

The code look like this:

```
WT.mean[, j=as.list(c(unlist(rkt(Year,WaterTemp)),count=length(WaterTemp))),
           by=list(RiverStationID, Month)]
```

I have already looked at the solutions of similar questions asked in this forum but they don't seem to solve this error. There is no erroneous values in the 'Year' column and it is supposed to be an integer. I realized that whenever I am reducing the size of the data set the code stops giving the error. But I don't want to split such a large dataset in small sets and do the analysis as it will be very time taking and doesn't solve the purpose of using a data table. How should I solve this?

Comment: Where is function `rkt` from? Try `as.list(as.numeric(c(unlist(rkt(...`

Comment: When you say it works for smaller sets, that means you have a problem in one part of your data. Examine group 49, which you can find with `WT.mean[,list(g=.GRP),by=list(RiverStationID, Month)][g==49L]`